# Showing the natural numbers $(\Bbb{N},<)$ do not admit quantifier elimination

Tags: model-theory, natural-numbers, quantifier-elimination

I have seen in lots of texts that the theory of $(\Bbb{N},<)$ does not admit quantifier elimination. I am trying to prove why, and although I can find hints in the literature, I am struggling to complete the proof.

I think the best method to do this would be to look at sentences in one variable $x$, and show that all of these sentences either admit the value True for all $x \in \Bbb{N}$ or False for all $x \in \Bbb{N}$. I can see that all atomic formulas made up of one variable will be of the form $x=x$ or $x<x$, and that any Boolean combinations of these atomic formulae will take the value or true or false for the entire domain. I think it therefore remains for me to find a sentence $\phi(x)$, that contains quantifiers, and only contains the one variable $x$ but is satisfied by a unique element of the domain, or a unique subset of the domain, such that it cannot be expressed by a Boolean combination of atomic formulas in one variable. My question is therefore, what should () be? Any help or hints appreciated, thank you!

Comment: How about $\forall y(x  = y \lor x < y)$?

Comment: So this is what I originally thought, but is this in one variable? Because it includes two variables, but only one is quantified, so I was worried it meant I couldn't use it to show quantifier elimination, as my quantifier-free sentences only rely on one variable

Comment: The bound variables don't count here, no.

Comment: The point is that you want a formula $\phi(x)$ that contains quantifiers, so these quantifiers will need to bind some variable other than $x$. You just have to be careful that $x$ is really the only _free variable_ in the formula (as in the formula suggested by Rob).