# Are there terminating methods to provide models of first-order theory formulae?

Tags: first-order-logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, decidability, quantifier-elimination

If a first-order theory is decidable on its existential fragment, does this imply that we have a method (that guarantees termination) to obtain models of existentially quantified formulae within this theory?

For instance, consider the theory of linear integer arithmetic. We know there is a terminating algorithm (i.e., Cooper's method) that performs quantifier elimination (QE) yielding a decision procedure if all variables are bounded by the quantifiers. This means that it can solve the satisfiability problem. But what if we want to ask for a model? **Is there a similar procedure that guarantees termination and offers a model?** Maybe some modification of Cooper's method?

**Generally, I am interested in the following**. Consider we have a formula with the shape `∃∀.φ` and `φ` is in theory `T`; then, I wonder whether there are `T` such that (one option or the other):

1. `T` admits QE and, if we perform elimination of `∀` in `∃∀.φ` and get `∃.φ'`; then, `T` has a terminating method that guarantees providing models of `∃.φ'`?
2. `T` is decidable, but does not admit QE (this seems to hold for naturals; e.g.,  [Showing the natural numbers $(\Bbb{N},<)$ do not admit quantifier elimination](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3911184/showing-the-natural-numbers-bbbn-do-not-admit-quantifier-elimination)); however, `T` has a terminating method that guarantees providing models of `∃∀.φ`?

I know there are SMT solvers, but I am rather interested in procedural methods of classic literature (e.g., Cooper, Ferrante-Rackoff etc). The question may be obvious; in such case, I am happy to just receive witnesses of those terminating algorithms that produce models in `T`.

PS: I am not sure if I should ask this question here or in the Computer Science Stack, sorry for the inconvenience in advance.

Comment: I'm concerned that while quantifier elimination is independent of choice of names of the elements, computing witnesses isn't

Comment: Hm... so it seems there is no such method that guarantees providing a model? Thanks for the response!